# Masonry grid onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, masonry

I'm building a section of products that I want to open and close on click, using masonry. 
I've added the onclick but as you can see
http://fi-testing.co.uk/zeffire-web/products.html
it's working but I'm having a few issues. 1) They all open onclick instead of just the relevant one 2) They don't realign when they resize (they overlap) 3) I want them to open slowly.

I've tried adding (still in the code) `slideDown(600, masonryUpdate);` to the .item function to sort the slow move, and to reupdate masonry, but that hasn't done anything.

This is the full function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".item").click(function(){
            $(".item").addClass("intro").slideDown(600, masonryUpdate);
        });
    });
```

I've tried using this http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html but I'm a newbie to it, so unsure where to add it, to align it with the 'onclick' part.

Any help would be appreciated? Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for: `$(this).addClass("intro").slideDown(600, masonryUpdate);`

Comment: yes! That sorts 1). Thank you.

Comment: I'd like the others to close once the current one opens, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle just the clicked element inside your *click event handler* by doing this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").click(function(){
        var a= $(this), b = a.parent();
        b.find(".intro").each(function(index){
           if(a !== $(this)) {
              // close this element since it's not the clicked one
              // $(this).slideUp() or $(this).addClass('close') if you have a custom class for closing elements
           }
        });
        a.addClass("intro").slideDown(600, masonryUpdate);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Fares, that works similar to Last1Here's comment, but I'd like the others to close once the current one opens, can you help?

Comment: @RachJenn I just edited my response to meet with what you want. Give it a try

Answer (score 1):

To fix issue 1) you would do what i commented

`$(this).addClass("intro").slideDown(600, masonryUpdate);`

for 2) and 3) you need to do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").click(function(){
        $(".intro").animate({"height": 500}, "fast").removeClass("intro"); // reset previous elements

        $(this).addClass("intro").slideDown("slow", function() { msnry.layout(); }); // refresh layout
    });
});
```